# Add custom fieldtype in keystone.js

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I am trying to add a hidden fieldtype called 'admin' which just has the user id of the person creating the model item.  This works fine locally but for some reason doesn't work on a server.  Here is what I did, maybe it is because I modified a file inside keystone/lib?

**/Models/Group.js**

```
var keystone = require('keystone'),
Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
 * Group Collection Model
 * =============
 */

var Group = new keystone.List('Group');

Group.add({
  name: { type: String, required: true, initial: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  groupId: { type: Types.Admin, required: true, initial: true, default: 'placeholder' }
});

Group.defaultColumns = 'name';
Group.register();
```

**/node_modules/keystone/lib/fieldTypes I added admin.js**

```
    /*!
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var util = require('util'),
  utils = require('keystone-utils'),
  super_ = require('../field');

/**
 * Text FieldType Constructor
 * @extends Field
 * @api public
 */

function admin(list, path, options) {
  this._nativeType = String;
  this._underscoreMethods = ['crop'];
  admin.super_.call(this, list, path, options);
}

/*!
 * Inherit from Field
 */

util.inherits(admin, super_);


/**
 * Crops the string to the specifed length.
 *
 * @api public
 */

admin.prototype.crop = function(item, length, append, preserveWords) {
  return utils.cropString(item.get(this.path), length, append, preserveWords);
};


/*!
 * Export class
 */

exports = module.exports = admin;
```

**/node_modules/keystone/lib/fieldTypes/index.js**

added this:

```
exports.Admin = require('./admin');
```

**/node_modules/keystone/templates/fields/admin**

added a form.jade and initial.jade template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "on a server", I will assume you mean on some Node.js hosting provider (i.e. Heroku, OpenShift, etc.). If that's the case and it's working locally, as you mentioned, I suspect that you may not be committing the `node_modules` folder in Git and therefore the changes you implemented are not being uploaded to your provider along with the rest of your code. Check your `.gitignore` file to see of `node_modules` is listed there. If it is, remove `node_modules` from he file, commit and push to your provider, and your app should work on your provider the same way it does locally.

That said, I'm currently working on a pull request ([#490](https://github.com/JedWatson/keystone/pull/490)) to KeystoneJS that will optionally add and automatically update `createdBy`, `createdAt`, `modifiedBy`, and `modifiedAt` to a model. We are currently discussing the best way to go about implementing it, but I suspect my PR, or a modified version of it, will soon be pulled and available in the near future.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Thanks!  I'll watch for that PR, data mapping will be really helpful.

Comment: You're quite welcome! An update on PR #490. We finally agreed on an implementation. I will be adding a new option the List called `track` that will allow you to enable `createdBy`, `createdAt`, `modifiedBy`, and `modifiedAt` on your list. Since that deviates from my original implementation in #490, I've rescinded that PR and will be submitting a new one in the next day or two. I will post an update here for your reference once I do.